# MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration is not working for Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created below sample application to test "MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration" functionality.

Here is my test scenario,

1. Created two console application with the same code.
2. Add one message in the queue
3. Run Console App1 which receives the message
4. Run Console App2 which receives the same message.

With below code I have setup MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration to 10 minutes.

To my understanding of "MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration" it should renew the lock automatically till 10 minutes and second console app should not receive the same message.

```
public class Program
{
    static string connectionString = "***";
    static string queueName = "firstqueue";
    
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //uncomment below if you would like to add message to queue
            //await CreateMessage(queueName, "Message 1 to test 'MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration'");
            await ReceiveMessagesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task CreateMessage(string queueName, string textMessage)
    {
        // create a Service Bus client 
        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
        {
            // create a sender for the queue 
            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

            // create a message that we can send
            ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(textMessage);

            // send the message
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent a single message to the queue: {queueName}");
        }
    }

    // handle received messages
    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body}");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // complete the message. messages is deleted from the queue. 
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }

    // handle any errors when receiving messages
    static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
    {
        var processorOptions = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
        {
            AutoCompleteMessages = false,
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock,
            PrefetchCount = 1
        };


        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
        {

            // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
            ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, processorOptions);

            // add handler to process messages
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

            // add handler to process any errors
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
            
            
            // start processing 
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // stop processing 
            Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
        }
    }
    static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(string queueName)
    {
        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
        {
            // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
            ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

            // add handler to process messages
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

            // add handler to process any errors
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

            // start processing 
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // stop processing 
            Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package are you using? and while you run the Console App 2 to receive the message, the Console App1 is still running?

Comment: @IvanYang I am using "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version "7.1.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using your code with `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` Version "7.1.1" and "7.1.2", the "MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration" functionality works well.

Here are my steps:

1.Send a message to the queue.

2.Run `Console App1` which receives the message

3.Keep `Console App1` running, and then run `Console App2`, there is no message received there. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

But if you first run `Console App1` which receives the message, then close the `Console App1` -> then run `Console App2`, you can see the message in `Console App2`. This is expected.

Comment: It wasn't working yesterday and today it started working. Probably I was doing something wrong but that a lot for the help.